Spotify api PUT /playlists/{playlist_id}/images returns 404 with valid ID
I am using spotify's api to create a playlist, add tracks and change the custom playlist cover image in quick succession. The createPlaylist() and populatePlaylist() functions work perfectly, even in quick succession. But the changePicture() function returns a 404 error.
Just to be clear, yes I did add "ugc-image-upload" in my scopes.
Main function
export const savePlaylist = async (token: string, spotifyUserId: string, body: any) => {
    const playlistInfo = await createPlaylist(token, spotifyUserId, body);

    // CHECKING IF THE ID TRULY EXISTS
    console.log("Playlist created with ID:", playlistInfo.id);

    await populatePlaylist(token, playlistInfo.id, body.tracks);

    // THIS ONLY WORKS WHEN USING A STATIC ID INSTEAD OF PLAYLISTINFO.ID
    const changePictureResult = await changePicture(playlistInfo.id, token);
    if (!changePictureResult) {
        console.error("Failed to change playlist picture.");
    }

    console.log("Playlist picture changed.");

    return playlistInfo;
}

CreatePlaylist function
const createPlaylist = async(token: string, userId:string, body:any) => {
    let url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`
    let axiosbody = {
        "name": body.title || "Custom Mix for you",
        "description": body.description || `This playlist was created specifically for you.`,
        "public": body.public || false,
        "collaborative": false
    }

    let result = await axios.post(url, axiosbody, {
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));

    if(!result) return null;
    return result.data;
}

changePicture function
const changePicture = async (playlistId:string, token:string) => {
    let base64Image = await convertBase64("Playlistcover_1.jpg")
    let url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistId}/images`;
    let result = await axios.put(url, base64Image, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).catch(error => console.error(error))

    if(!result) return false;
    return result.data;
}


May you please Introduce a short delay (a few seconds) between the playlist creation/population and the image update calls. This can sometimes help mitigate issues related to propagation delays.
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

You may also want to enhance logging around the ‘playlistInfo.id’ to ensure it's not null or undefined. Also, confirm the format of the ID and compare it with the format of your static ID which works.
console.log("Playlist ID:", playlistInfo.id);

Another way might help you solve the problem:
export const savePlaylist = async (token, spotifyUserId, body) => {
  createPlaylist(token, spotifyUserId, body)
.then(playlistInfo => {
  console.log("Playlist created with ID:", playlistInfo.id);
  return populatePlaylist(token, playlistInfo.id, body.tracks)
    .then(() => {
      return playlistInfo; 
    });
})
.then(playlistInfo => {
  return changePicture(playlistInfo.id, token);
})
.then(changePictureResult => {
  if (!changePictureResult) {
    console.error("Failed to change playlist picture.");
  } else {
    console.log("Playlist picture changed.");
  }
  return changePictureResult; // Optional: Handle or return result
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error("An error occurred:", error);
});
}


Using a sleep function does work, but is not really desirable.I do understand that this might be the only feasable option, since the issue lies within spotify's resource readiness.
And yes I have confirmed the playlist id's are the exact same format as the static id's. I used previously created id's that were logged as a static id, to make sure there is absolutely no problem with getting the userId.

@Goldquick I update my answer.  Can you please try it.
